# Configure Google Translate API v2 on localhost

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-api, localhost, google-translate

does anyone here knows how to configure Google Translate API 2 to work in localhost without paying for each translation since I just want to do some test before putting it live...

Here is what I have tried so far:

In google developers console, under APIs & auth > Credential, I have configured the key for browser application to http://www.example.com, as well as the Client ID for web application. In my host file I added the line 127.0.0.1 http://www.example.com

I also tried to set the referes of the Key for browser aplicaiton to localhost, does not work either

When I call the translation, it returns the error Daily Limit Exceeded.

Anyone can help?

Regards

Comment: I haven't used this API, but I would not be at all surprised to find that example.com has far exceeded its daily limit.  It probably did that in the minute after midnight.

Comment: oh that's great -_- i'll need something else then...